# how to add `ts` files for debugging in prod?

Tags: angular, debugging, typescript, deployment, angular-cli

I am new to angular2.

I have created an app and want to deploy it to prod.

I scaffold it using angular-cli

So i build it using `npm build -dev` or `npm build -prod`.

However it deploys into `dist` folder `js` and not `ts` files

even when using `npm build -dev`.

How can I add the `ts` files as well so i can debug it on prod via chrome browser as well?

do I need to add them manually?

Comment: I am searching solution for the same scenario. @Elad Benda2, were you able to find solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for source maps.

enable them in your `tsconfig.json` to see typescript in Chrome

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    ...
  }
```

However, the Chrome Dev Tools seem to have issues with typescript and source maps. It's not a reliable way to debug your application.

Comment: thanks, but before that - how do i include the `ts` files in my build destination folder `dist` ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Did you generate source maps?

Comment: i had this flag true already, but then how do i debug via the browser?

Answer (score 0):

not sure about ts files because "[TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript", but try "ng build" (without --prod) this will build without bundling, so you should at least see your js source files.

Comment: It's hard to debug generated js files. I want to debug the TypeScript  code i wrote. That's why i have asked how to add them to the deployment folder.